# MySQL Trigger Syntax Error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to implement a trigger in `MySQL` that will automatically add/modify a column when another one is added/modified. Basically I want it to save a `type` as a [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) in the `type_sanitized` column when a value is added/modified into `type`.

This is my initial try:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ArticleTypes.insert_sanitized_article_type;

CREATE TRIGGER 'insert_sanitized_article_type'
AFTER INSERT
ON 'ArticleTypes'
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.type_sanitized = LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(NEW.type), ' ', '-'));

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ArticleTypes.update_sanitized_article_type;

CREATE TRIGGER 'update_sanitized_article_type'
AFTER UPDATE
ON 'ArticleTypes'
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.type_sanitized = LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(NEW.type), ' ', '-'));
```

After seeing suggestions online, I have tried adding delimiters like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ArticleTypes.insert_sanitized_article_type;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 'insert_sanitized_article_type'
AFTER INSERT
ON 'ArticleTypes'
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.type_sanitized = LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(NEW.type), ' ', '-'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ArticleTypes.update_sanitized_article_type;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 'update_sanitized_article_type'
AFTER UPDATE
ON 'ArticleTypes'
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.type_sanitized = LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(NEW.type), ' ', '-'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following error for both of them:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''insert_sanitized_article_title'
AFTER INSERT
ON 'ArticleTypes'
FOR EACH ROW 
BE' at line 1
```

This is my first time creating triggers in MySQL so it might be obvious but I haven't been able to figure it out in 2 hours of searching so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ArticleTypes.insert_sanitized_article_type;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_sanitized_article_type
AFTER INSERT
ON ArticleTypes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET @type_sanitized = LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(@type), ' ', '-'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ArticleTypes.update_sanitized_article_type;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_sanitized_article_type
AFTER UPDATE
ON ArticleTypes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET @type_sanitized = LOWER(REPLACE(TRIM(@type), ' ', '-'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ahhhh such a minor detail ... That fixed it, thank you!

Comment: However, nothing is added to type_sanitized when inserting or updating type. Any ideas why?

Comment: ArticleTypes only includes type and type_sanitized, which are both VARCHAR(100). type is PK, type_sanitized is unique.